# How to customize section numbers to specific letters?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

Usually, when you divide your document in sections, you get the usual roman numbering

```
\begin{document}

\section{first section}
\subsection{first sub section}


\section{second section}
```

And that's all good, but I need to do something different. What I need is to replace the first level numbering with four letters: T, S, D and E. So that when I run the above, I get something like this

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Did you know about [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters#Counter_style)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to redefine `\thesection` for example

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\ifcase\value{section}?\or T\or S\or D\or E\else ?\fi}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! You sir are my savior.